# Redefine a class using byte-buddy

Tags: java, instrumentation, byte-buddy

I want to redefine the Source class which is already defined in an existing framework. I want to automatically replace the original instances of the Source class with my enhanced class.  I do not have access to the code that creates the Source objects so the class substitution must perform automatically under the hood. Is it possible to do this using byte-buddy ?

```
    ByteBuddyAgent.install();
    Source source = new ByteBuddy()
            .subclass(Source.class)
            .method(named("hello")).intercept(MethodDelegation.to(Target.class))
            .defineMethod("myNewMethod", void.class).intercept(MethodDelegation.to(Target.class))
            .make()
            .load(Source.class.getClassLoader(),
                    ClassReloadingStrategy.fromInstalledAgent())
            .getLoaded()
            .newInstance();
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to redefine a class using Byte Buddy. To do so, you would use the `ByteBuddy::redefine` or `ByteBuddy::rebase` methods instead of subclassing. The most canonical way to use these features is by defining a Java Agent for what you can use the `AgentBuilder`.

Comment: Ok. Thanks ! Adding new methods should be though allowed only in case of subclassing, otherwise I get a   **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: class redefinition failed: attempted to change the schema (add/remove fields) **

Comment: What I'm trying to do is actually this: I have an instance of an object which implements a given interface. The current implementation creates a new object of the same interface and delegates most of the calls to the original object. It also changes some of the methods and adds some methods .What I want to achieve is use instrumentation so that I should not always add a new method to my decorated object every time when original interface changes. I think that the best way is to use subclassing and to delegate all methods of the interface using **method(isDeclaredBy(Source.class))** to original

Comment: You cannot replace a class by using a Java agent, you can only add custom dispatching logic inside of a method. I recommend you to look into the `Advice` component.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I think I do not need the agent at all. I will only  subclass and redirect by default all the methods of the instance to the original object. All the methods that I have to rewrite or to add will be handled via defineMethod(new methods)  or   method(named(..)).intercept.() - existing methods